# SQL Server Pivot with YEAR() Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using PIVOT in SQL Server to aggregate SalesQuota by YEAR(QuotaDate).

I want to know why this version doesn't work:

[image: not working]

But this one does:

[image: works]

Seemingly it doesn't like when I use the YEAR() function inside of PIVOT, so instead I simply made a nested SELECT in the FROM statement before the PIVOT.

Any thoughts?

p.s. Does anyone know how I can get the brackets off of my outputs?

[image: image here]

I'm new to SQL, the column names are numbers so I put the brackets around them, but it looks ugly in the final output.

Comment: Please add your code to the question (using code formatting) and you'll get much better responses

Comment: what if you alias the year as '2011' etc?

Comment: For some reason once I ran it as a stored proc it removed the brackets... I had tried aliasing it and it kept the brackets...

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this using conditional aggregation.  You can try double quotes:

```
select concat( . . . ) as salesperson,
       sum(case when year(quotadata) = 2011 then salesquota end) as "2011",
       sum(case when year(quotadata) = 2012 then salesquota end) as "2012",
       sum(case when year(quotadata) = 2013 then salesquota end) as "2013",
       sum(case when year(quotadata) = 2014 then salesquota end) as "2014"
from . . . 
group by concat( . . . )
```